# Fetch data from database from multiple tables matching condition

Tags: wordpress, mysql

I want to fetch data from the database. I have three tables in my database: `listing_master_residential`, `listing_master_condo` and `listing_master_commercial`. There is one primary key, `Ml_num`, in all tables. I want to search the data from one table which matches mls number table.

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $mls=$_POST['mls_number'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM listing_master_residential,
        listing_master_condo, 
        listing_master_commercial  
        INNER JOIN listing_master_residential AS res ON res.Ml_num=Ml_num
        INNER JOIN listing_master_condo AS con ON con.Ml_num=Ml_num
        INNER JOIN listing_master_commercial AS com ON com.Ml_num=Ml_num
        WHERE Ml_num='$mls'";
    $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    foreach ( $result as $row) {
        echo $row->Lot_code."<br/>";
        echo $row->Ml_num."<br/>";
        echo $row->Acres;
        echo $row->Addr."<br/>";
        echo $row->Bath_tot;
        echo $row->Br;
        echo $row->Br_plus;
    }
}
```

With the above, I get an error:

> Column 'Ml_num' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: Questions here should be specific to wordpress and yours is about sql syntax error. This kind of questions might get an answer but there are better forums to ask them.

Comment: hello sir i am using wordpress  here for develop a wordpress plugin

Comment: hi you have any suggestion for how to fetch data

Answer (score 0):

Because the column Ml_num is in all the tabels you need to address it with the Fully Qualified Name, for instance con.Ml_num

I did also notice your joining all the tabels twice, once with implicit join and once with ANSI join
The implicit join will result in a cross join because there are no join conditions in the where clause.